# Pillow - Change every pixel's RGB value

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm new to python and am trying to learn pil. I want to lower every pixels rgb value by 1. For examle (100, 239, 54) should be (99, 238, 53). However once the picture is saved it doesn't have the pixel values i saved to it. But not identical to the original picture either.

```
from PIL import Image 

img = Image.open('dog2.jpg', 'r') 
imgdata = list(img.getdata())
print(imgdata[:5])

imgdata = [val for sublist in imgdata for val in sublist]
for i, pixbit in enumerate(imgdata):
    imgdata[i] -= 1
imgdata = list(zip(*[iter(imgdata)]*3))

print(imgdata[:5])

newimg = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
newimg.putdata(imgdata)
newimg.save('newimg.jpg')

img = Image.open('newimg.jpg', 'r')
print(list(img.getdata())[:5])
```

The three prints prints:

```
[(36, 79, 86), (36, 79, 86), (36, 79, 86), (36, 79, 86), (37, 80, 87)]
[(35, 78, 85), (35, 78, 85), (35, 78, 85), (35, 78, 85), (36, 79, 86)]
[(36, 79, 88), (36, 79, 88), (36, 79, 88), (36, 79, 88), (36, 79, 88)]
```

The last print should be identical to the second one.

Could anyone explain to me why this is? Thank you!

Comment: One good thing you can learn as soon as possible is that you really should avoid `for` loops with Python image processing - they are dead slow. Try and use Numpy or PIL functions or OpenCV functions in preference.

Comment: Thank for the tip, I will look in to that aswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a lossy compression format, which means you should not expect to retrieve the exact same pixel values you saved. If you want exact values, you should probably try [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Comment: Aha i expected it might be something like that. So is there no way to decide exact rgb values to a JPEG?

Comment: No. As the name "lossy compression" says, the LSB-level details are lost.